# вывести echo после цикла

Tags: php

**первое echo правильно (это и понятно), второе echo выводит последнюю запись (это тоже понятно почему), а как можно заставить второе echo выводить именно ту строку из БД, которая мне нужна, например, 3**

```php
$id_= null;
for($i = 1; $i<50; $i++ ) {
$id_i = $id_.$i; 

if(isset($id_i)){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pers WHERE `id` = '$id_i'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    foreach($result as $row){
        $id_i = $row['id'];
        $mi_i = $row['mi'];
        $ya_i = $row['ya'];
        $che_i = $row['che']; 
        echo "   ".$id_i."   ".$mi_i."  ".$ya_i."  ".$che_i."   ";
    }
    $result->free();
} else{
    echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;
}

}
else{
    $mi_i = "";
    $ya_i = "";
    $che_i = "";
}

}
if($id_i=3){
echo " mi  ".$mi_i;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_= null;
for($i = 1; $i<50; $i++ ) {
$id_i = $id_.$i; 

if(isset($id_i)){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pers WHERE `id` = '$id_i'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    foreach($result as $row){
        $id_i = $row['id'];
        $mi_i = $row['mi'];
        $ya_i = $row['ya'];
        $che_i = $row['che']; 
       //echo "   ".$id_i."   ".$mi_i."  ".$ya_i."  ".$che_i."   ";
       $array [$id_i] = $mi_i." ".$ya_i." ".$che_i;
    }
    $result->free();
} else{
   echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;
}
}
else{
    $mi_i = "";
    $ya_i = "";
    $che_i = "";
}

}
if($id_i=3){
//echo " mi  ".$mi_i;
echo $array[$id_3];}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_= null;
for($i = 1; $i<50; $i++ ) {
$id_i = $id_.$i; 

if(isset($id_i)){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pers WHERE `id` = '$id_i'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
$sch = 0;
    foreach($result as $row){
        $sch = $sch + 1;
        $id_i = $row['id'];
        $mi_i = $row['mi'];
        $ya_i = $row['ya'];
        $che_i = $row['che']; 
        if($sch == 3){
          echo "   ".$id_i."   ".$mi_i."  ".$ya_i."  ".$che_i."   ";
        }
       //echo "   ".$id_i."   ".$mi_i."  ".$ya_i."  ".$che_i."   ";
       $array [$id_i] = $mi_i." ".$ya_i." ".$che_i;
    }
    $result->free();
} else{
   echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;
}
}
else{
    $mi_i = "";
    $ya_i = "";
    $che_i = "";
}

}
```